# Advice needed with Teamcity artifact paths

Tags: teamcity, artifact

For a .NET Developer, the Teamcity artifact paths are not very straightforward.

Per project I do, I have a folder called BuildTools and, within it, folders called Drops and Inputs (drops being the reports and outputs inputs being the config files for various command line apps).

BuildTools/Drops/NDependOut => GenericSolution/Drops/NDepend

Is this correct? BuildTools is from the root of the (custom) checkout dir, and then GenericSolution is from the root of the artifacts path (Called "Artifacts" folder).

The other problem I have is that the NDepend report has a lot of images etc in the same folder as the .html file. How would I upload this? Do I upload the entire folder (in which case, is the syntax above correct?)

Answer (score 1):

In general this is right. TeamCity has an option to zip artifacts before publish. For that use the following syntax

Folder/folder/**/* => destfolder/archive.zip

Another trick is to use TeamCity service message to publish artifacts dynamically from build script.